# Highlight cells cumulatively based on less than or equal to value in specific cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

I feel this is possible, but I have been unable to get anything working using conditional formatting and am not quite sure what direction to take in VBA.

I want to highlight cells across a row,N2 through AN2, green if the value of the cell plus previous cells is less than or equal to the value of another cell, C2.

If C2 is 1,000, I would want N2 at 300 highlighted green (cumulative total 300), O2 at 600 highlighted green (cumulative total 900), P2 at 100 highlighted green (cumulative total 1,000), and Q2 at 150 not highlighted as the cumulative of it plus the previous cells is 1,150, above the 1,000 in the reference cell.

Can this be accomplished through conditional formatting or what should I do in VBA to make this happen?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that cell M2 is empty, then you want to highlight any cell that is less than or equal to the value in C2 minus the sum of cells to the left of this cell beginning at M2. You can do that with Conditional Formatting using the formula

```
=$C$2-SUM($M2:M2)
```

Select the range you want to format (N2:AN2) and set Conditional Formatting as shown below:

[image]

If cell M2 is not empty, you can still make this work, but you need to use a slightly more complicated formula in the Conditional Formatting rule:

```
=$C$2+N2-SUM($N2:N2)
```

Comment: @Blackie, the second formula will color Q2 also.  Won't `$C$2-SUM($N2:N2)` do the job regardless of what's in M2?

Comment: @Bandersnatch I double-checked and the second formula does not highlight Q2. Changing the formula to `$C$2-SUM($N2:N2)` results in N2 being highlighted and not O2:Q2, which is not correct.

Comment: @Blackie, I couldn't get this to work correctly at ALL in Excel 2011 for Mac.  I could highlight the first 3 cells if I used a formula of `=IF(N2<=$C$2-SUM($L2:L2),1,0)`, but when I changed the range to `$K2:K2`, it highlighted all 4.  `$M2:M2` highlighted 2, and `$N2:N2` highlighted 1.  At least there's a pattern, but sheesh! it makes no sense.  So if your approach works, more power to you and good luck to OP. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I used the last mechanism presented in the dialog:  using a formula to decide which to format. The formula was `=SUM($N2:N2)<=$C2` and with a second's thought, one sees that's precisely what `Blackwood` did in the different mechanism. Except that I started in column N, not M.

The problem for me was that it highlighted all four example cells. Not just N:P, but N:Q. No reason I could see. I limited it to just N2, then copied it and pasted formatting onto the other cells over to Q2. No dice. Bit of an impasse.

Then I limited it to N2, copied N2, and pasted to the other cells. Not just formats, but pasted value and all. Edited back in the values and it worked. Just like it should.

OK, so that's doable, though obnoxious. But... I experimented in row 3. Copied N2 to N3, and started in.

First shot out of the gate worked. Entered the other values given then tried copying N3 and pasting only formats onto the other cells. Worked. Perfectly, even though it did not in first efforts in row 2.

I have no explanation for that, except... no... no explanation. Just none. Closed the file and did it again in a new one and the very same thing happened. By the way, I'm in 2022, using version 2205, so while it's a decent thought that whatever the reason is for me is the same as it was for OP, or `Bandersnatch` on his Mac version, there have been a lot of changes in the four years since and it may be coincidental.